# Can an object contain only accessor properties(object should not have any data properties)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
var student={};
 Object.defineProperty(student,"name",{
                        get:function(){
                            this.name;
                          },
                       set:function(){
                            this.name=name;
                          }
                  });
```

I am assuming that if i assign student.name="xyz",a name property will get add to student object.I in confusion when and how to use accessor properties.

Comment: What are you expecting `this.name=name` to do?

Comment: so what you mean is  this.name=name this statement searches name property in student object if it did not find it searches in its prototype and so on...hence it  causes infinite loop .right?

Comment: Settters and getters can be used to control what is being set or for getting computed properties or for accessing properties that are stored in some private location.  They provide code control over the value rather than just letting an external agent set or get the value directly.  There are many ways they are useful, but they do not replace the need to store values you want to retain somewhere.

Comment: I understood your point.Thanks for the reply friend.

Comment: "*Can an object contain only accessor properties?*" - Yes of course.

Comment: @bergi however thats slightly unuseful...

Answer (score 0):

`Object.defineProperty` is used to work on properties like `configurable`, `enumerable`, `writable`, `get`, `set`, etc. With get and set in your code, I dont see any point of doing what. You might want to use them when you for ex. mutate data by writing it in or getting it back.

More obvious benefits of changing those properties you can see with for ex. `writable`:

```
var obj = { name: 'foo' }

obj.name // 'foo'
obj.name = 'bar' 
obj.name // 'bar'

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {writable: false}
obj.name = 'foo'
obj.name // 'bar'
```

Or `enumerable`:

```
var o = {name: 'foo', lastName: 'bar'}
Object.defineProperty(o, 'name', {enumerable: false})
for(var prop in o) { console.log(prop)} // lastName
```

Answer (score 0):

A good usecase would be modifying the object when one property is set, e.g:

```
 const person = {
   firstName: "Jonas",
   lastName: "W.",

   get fullName(){ return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;},
   set fullName(name){
     const [first, last] = name.split(" ");
     this.firstName = first;
     this.lastName = last;
   }
 };
```

So one can do:

```
 person.fullName = "Max Mustermann";
 console.log(person.firstName, person.lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

A use case for property accessors is when you need to perform some data validation on the property being set.

```
const Vehicle = function(){};

Object.defineProperty(Vehicle.prototype, "_wheels", {
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
});

const Bike = function() {}
Bike.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);

Object.defineProperty(Bike.prototype, "wheels", {
  get: function() {
    return this._wheels;
  },
  set: function(numWeels) {
    if (numWeels > 2) {
      throw new Error('Sorry, too many wheels!');
      return;
    }
    this._wheels = numWeels;
  }
});

myBike = new Bike();
myBike.wheels = 3;
console.log(myBike.wheels);
```